# how to make Roles and manage Users?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, roles, asp.net-roles

in my Project i need to define 3 roles :

1. SuperAdmin
2. Admin
3. RegisteredMembers

I also have Table which named "Users" that stores information such as:

1. fristName
2. lastName
3. Birthday
4. Username
5. Password
   .
   .
   .
   and etc

How can i make Roles recognize which user is for which Role when users try to log on to website?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you creating a `Users` table is just the first step. You also need a `Role` table and a `UserRole` many-to-many relationship table to store which user belongs to which role(In a simple scenario).

That's for the database part of the whole concept.

Then, on the code side...since you're providing different tables than the ones in the [AspNetMembership](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/membership) you need to also implement a [custom membership provider](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-membership-provider/), [custom role provider](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-role-provider/) and presumably a [custom membership user](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-membership-user/).